# How to have one main JavaScript file for multiple pages?

Tags: javascript

I have a small application with two pages: the login page and the main page. My problem is that when I use just one main JavaScript file for both pages (like it's recommanded) I get a lot of ReferenceError because some variables on a page are not defined on the other one...

e.g:

Line of code for the login page

```
copyrightYear.textContent = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Main page complains

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
```

How can I fix that? Don't tell me I have to say `if(copyrightYear) { do stuff }` everytime, it's just a nightmare if I have to do that for every variable

Comment: you should use functions

Comment: First of all, what is "copyrightYear"? Is it item id? Is it reference to element made by querySelector?

Comment: Your JS is not type of "main", if it has hardcoded references to the elements on pages, so it's not suitable to be used on multiple pages.

Comment: if you have that much difference, nobody would recommend you to put all your js code in one file, if still want to use one file, just create functions for one file whichever has less js code

Comment: @Magiczne It's a reference to an element made by querySelector, yes. And since this element does not exist in the main page I get a ReferrenceError

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two answers for you:

#### The recommendation isn't a dictate

> My problem is that when I use just one main JavaScript file for both pages (like it's recommanded)

That's a **very** general recommendation. It doesn't apply to every situation. There's no point in loading code in a page that won't use that code.

If you have code that you use in both pages, and also page-specific code, it's **absolutely fine** to have a file that both pages share and also page-specific files:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="page1.js"></script>
```

If you're really worried about the extra HTTP request (much less of an issue these days than it used to be), use modules and a bundler like Webpack or Rollup that will create a bundle combining the main module with page 1's module for page 1 and another bundle combining the main module with page 2's module for page 2.

But even then, the extra HTTP request may be *better* for your users, if you expect them to go from page1 to page2 in a reasonable timeframe. The reason is that if you have `main.js` and `page1.js`/`page2.js` and you allow caching of them, when the user goes to page1 they get `main.js` and `page1.js`, and then when they go to page2 `main.js` comes out of their local cache and they only have to load `page2.js`. In contrast, if you had a single bundle file for each page, they'd have to re-download all of that common code when going from page1 to page2 (or vice versa). But if you expect a visitor to visit **either** page1 or page2 but not the other one, you save the HTTP request by using page-specific bundles.

There's really no one-size-fits-all solution. :-) There are all sorts of considerations.

Note that HTTP/1.1 made additional HTTP requests more efficient and is nearly universally supported, and [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) makes them **a lot** more efficient, effectively eliminating the case for reducing the number of HTTP requests as part of the page startup. All major modern browsers support HTTP/2 as do up-to-date web servers.

#### Put the code for each page in a function

If you really want to keep a single page, put the code that's specific to each page in functions for those pages, and then have code in the main part of the file call the appropriate function based on `location.pathname`.

Comment: depending on the size of the main, I advocate against the bundle because you'll need to download the same thing twice while having separate file allow the usage of cache

Comment: @jonatjano - Agreed, there's no one-size-fits-all solution. :-) There are all sorts of considerations. For instance, a bundle would make sense if the you'd expect people to go to page1 but not to page2 or vice-versa. But if they're going to go from page1 to page2 (or vice-versa) within a reasonable timeframe, separate files avoids the repeated download of the shared code (since it can come from cache).

Answer (score 2):

You figured it out, you have to check this for every variable. But generally it's much more convenient to use functions and only call these functions when you need them.

So for example, say you want to set some copyrightYear (even tough this shouldn't be set via JS, you should generate this on Backend side to have it in the source code)

You have something like this:

```
function updateYear() {
  // here you do your magic of selecting the element, setting the year, whatever.
}

// another function, totally unrealted to updateYear()
function toggleMenu() {
  // some function where you toggle the menu if you click somewhere
  // like: button.addEventListener('click', () => {} );
}
```

And in your JS file you have one block where you call all these functions:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.elementForYear') {
  updateYear(); // here we call it because we are sure this element exists... so everything inside function must work
}
if (document.querySelector('.myMenu') {
  toggleMenu(); // if the element myMenu exists, we know we can add these toggle Functionality.
}
```

You can also add these if inside the function and call the function regardless of if it's needed or not, that's up to you and up to coding guidelines.

Generally I find it makes sense to have one function only rely on one (or max two to three elements if it's some toggling of other elements) ... And then you just check for one element. And if this one element exists you can go ahead and call the function.